# How do I set Google Chrome new tab page to Monero Stackexchange URL?

Tags: user-guide

I've been researching the chrome settings but have not been successful in my quest.

I have found how to set the URL for the home button, but does anyone know how to change the "default new tab" opening to monero.stackexchange.com URL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the site topic. This should be asked on Super User (of which I'm sure there are many duplicates there).

Answer (score 7):

Search for "Blank New Tab Page" extension which allows either blank pages or a specific URL to be utilized.

Answer (score 3):

Various resources state that this is not an option in Chrome. If this information is still accurate, you would have te resort to an extension. More on that here:

[google product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/gZ3TBoJQN6A)

[stack exchange](https://superuser.com/questions/901417/how-do-i-change-the-default-chrome-tab-page)

[howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11412/choose-custom-new-tab-pages-in-chrome/)

Answer (score 2):

From a quick look around i'm 95% certain you cant currently re-allocate the "open new tab page" to a specific address on chrome at the moment, but see below for chrome extensions that apparently do facilitate the user for this requirement.

[New Tab Redirect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-new-tab-page/mgmiemnjjchgkmgbeljfocdjjnpjnmcg?hl=en)

[Awesome New Tab Page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-new-tab-page/mgmiemnjjchgkmgbeljfocdjjnpjnmcg?hl=en)

[Google Art Project](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-art-project/akimgimeeoiognljlfchpbkpfbmeapkh?hl=en)

[Momentum](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/momentum/laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca?hl=en)

*Please note that these suggestions were sourced from this previous question from another site- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna?hl=en